# Function always returns false after commiting sharedpreferences without any error

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences, return-value, commit

I problematic parts are the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements
    OnContactsInteractionListener, OnAdModeListener {

private SharedPreferences sp;
private SharedPreferences.Editor ed;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sp = this.getSharedPreferences("me.name",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    ed = sp.edit();



private boolean parseIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("SHOW_PHONE_CALL_LIST")
            && sp.getBoolean("SHOW_SECOND", false)) {
        try {
            goToPage(1);
            int random = sp.getInt("RANDOM", 9999);
            counterAdsAndLoad("2", random);
            //ed is editor object
            ed.putString("MP3PATH", "");
            ed.putBoolean("SHOW_SECOND", false);
            ed.commit()
            return true;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    ed.remove("RANDOM").commit();
    return false;

}
```

I debugged because of the unreasonably bad behavior, I saw the following:
The if condition was true, as I expected and after the second `commit()` the program jumps to `return false`.

What could be the reason?

Comment: instead of using commit for each and every editor transaction use one at last i.e after ed.remove("RANDOM"); ed.commit.

Comment: I tried, but it is still jumping from the "if" section to `return false` after `commit()`

Comment: for the very first time "sp.getBoolean("SHOW_SECOND", false)" this expression returns false, if it is not yet created. and your function returns false, I would like to know where are you storing "SHOW_SECOND" value to true?

Comment: If I am right, the function doesn't care what value it is. It should commit() and return true in the if section. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are Wrong the second conditional statement in your "if" condition i.e. sp.getBoolean("SHOW_SECOND", false) will return always false, because in share preference "SHOW_SECOND" is not yet created and always return "false" (ie second parameter in your statement). changing "false" to "true" will work.

Comment: That is not the problem here, I misunderstood you, I thought you mean the commit part. The condition is not the problem here, it is true since the debugger goes line by line, it is doing it's job, but after the last line ( `ed.commit()`) the program is not going to the next line ( `return true`), it is going to  `return false`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39811/discussion-between-vinaykumar-and-keybee)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements
OnContactsInteractionListener, OnAdModeListener {

private SharedPreferences sp;
```

...

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  sp = getSharedPreferences("me.name",
        MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private boolean parseIntent(Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals("SHOW_PHONE_CALL_LIST")
        && sp.getBoolean("SHOW_SECOND", false)) {
    try {
        goToPage(1);
        int random = sp.getInt("RANDOM", 9999);
        counterAdsAndLoad("2", random);
        //ed is editor object
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putString("MP3PATH", "");
        ed.putBoolean("SHOW_SECOND", false);
        ed.commit()
        return true;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
 }
 SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
 ed.remove("RANDOM").commit();
 return false;
```

}

Comment: Why is this different than instantiating in `onCreate()`?

Comment: once you have performed commit, you have to call edit() again to put or remove new values

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have follow this.

Create a SharedPrefrences reference.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Create a reference of SharedPreferncesEditor

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

Put Values in Editor

```
editor.putBoolean("SHOW_SECOND", true); 
editor.putString("MP3_PATH", "");
```

Commit the edits at the end

```
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I have all this, and I tried commiting at the end. After commit, it still jumps to `return false`... Could it be a problem how I declare the editor object? I will edit my question.

Comment: where did you use sp = getSharedPreferences("xyz", MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: in the `onCreate()` method